# Money Rain Glitchy Render (Fine in Viewport)

Tags: rendering

Trying to render a short money rain animation.

What I've done:

1. Imported money as an Image plane
2. Added subdivisions and subdivision modifier to 2
3. Added cloth simulation to the plane
4. Added two forces (Wind, Turbulent)
5. Baked
6. Created particle system with render plane as the object. Adjusted settings and set to hair
7. Created instance reel from particles

It looks absolutely fine in the viewport but turns into a glitchy mess when rendering.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the problem appears even if I render just one original "dollar". I tried to UV unwrap but it doesn't seem to be doing anything

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

The solution was to change the sub-modifier to 1 for "render" so both values would be 1.

I guess the reason for the glitch is that the physics were baked while the sub-modifier was at 1 and during rendering it was increased to 2 and that caused the mesh to break.